# Unable to enter data in child window

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-application

1. `Step-1.` Click the link from the parent window.The new window gets opened. Say it
   as a child window.
2. `Step-2.` In child window, not able to enter data in
       the field using selenium webDriver.

**code:**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='topButtonRow']/input[5]")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(windowHandles.size());
Iterator<String> it = windowHandles.iterator();
String wHandle = null;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    wHandle = it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(wHandle);
    if (driver.getCurrentUrl().equals("https://uat.omnilife.com.au/OmniLifeWeb/#/quotes/300020fb-e61b-439a-b5d1-5459976ee59b?crmReferenceId=006p0000004VCAE&page=client&save=true&complete=true")) {
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='client-occupation']")).sendKeys("Comput");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("[ Computing Professional ]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='update-client']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='trmCheck']")).isSelected();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='quote-settings']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("50000"); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='quoteResultGrid']/div/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/input")).isSelected();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='saveToCRMBulk']")).click();
    }
  }
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandle);
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message that you're getting?

Comment: Maybe this `@id='client-occupation'` element is not text field but some element above it, or you have a frame that you need to switch to in the child window?

Answer (score 1):

- You haven't switched to the child window yet, because when you have used `getWindowHnadles` you will get all the current windows.
- So when you are iterating, its still in the main window, and the element to enter data won't be there in the main window so that you will get an error.
- use a condition so that it won't execute if handle is of main window. like this

  `if(wHandle!=parentWindowHandle)`